# Combining Fight through the Pain and Force of Personality?

Tags: star-wars-saga-edition

In Star wars Saga edition, if I have both `Fight through the Pain` and `Force of Personality` can I add my Cha bonus to my will defense and use it for my damage threshold as a reaction, or is 'testing' against damage threshold not something you can 'react to'?

Comment: From the generic description of the two feats I would say yes.  Force of Personality allows you to sub in your CHA for your WIS to determine the value of your Will Defense, and Fight through the Pain says nothing about how your Will Defense is determined, only that you can use it to determine the damage threshold. Not sure how I would feel about that as a GM.

Comment: It's a question of whether you can 'react' to your damage threshold being met.

Comment: Are these Feats or Traits and what books are they in?

Comment: @TysonoftheNorthwest They're feats. And they're both from `Galaxy at War`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rule that *Force of Personality* does not require an in the moment reaction on your character's part, so this is something that would be "always on".  If it is always on then the will save you have after figuring it in is what you use for all subsequent abilities.  In that case it shouldn't unbalance the game at all since you use your Cha **OR** Wis, not Cha **AND** Wis, your total save won't be outside expected values.

Since your will save is not wildly unbalanced I would have no problem with using it in conjunction with *Fight Through the Pain*.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that in case of ambiguity it's important to consider whether or not there's a real game impact. I'd say that it really doesn't matter so much what the rules state on this particular issue as how it will impact your game.

As far as 'reacting' to the damage threshold I'm not terribly familiar with Saga edition, but I'd say probably not, just to keep the damage threshold from being a totally worthless measurement, and also because it preserves the original balance. It's not really that either camp wins this argument, but if there's a decreased value placed on the damage threshold it provides more incentives to combat, and I'm assuming given how I've played the game that you want to keep the combat at a lower rate.